# Finding orthogonality with matrices

Tags: matrices

I know that if the dot product of two vectors is $0$, the vectors are orthogonal.

But how does this apply to matrices, specifically a $3 \times 1$ and a $1 \times 3$?

I know how to muliply these together, but that is going to give me a matrix, not a scalar.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalMatrix.html

This tells me how to find out if two matrices are orthogonal, but only if they are $n \times n$.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you understand from the article?

Comment: Orthogonality of pair of vectors is different than orthogonality of the matrix.  Also, if you multiply 1x3 matrix with 3x1 matrix you'll get scalar, just like in case of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Given two vectors **x** and **y**, you can represent them as column matrices. Verifying if they are orthogonal can be achieved by doing the multiplication of one of the vectors with the transpose of the other. You have to put the transpose of the vector in front of the other like this $x^Ty$. If the result of the multiplication is **0**, there is orthogonality. Note that $x^Ty$ is also given by $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$$
And thus, if $\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i = 0$ (with *n* being the number of rows of your column matrix (or the number of columns of your transpose matrix)), there is orthogonality.